# Best approach to create users ACL menu

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a webapp using Spring 4 with some menus and sub menus.

```
-Menu 1
  -sub menu 1
  -sub menu 2
-Menu 2
  -sub menu 1
  -sub menu 2
```

I want to manage users rights (read/write access).
The user acl and the entire menu are editable in the app dashboard.

For example I can create a new menu and give access to all users or just to some users.

The thing is I have some Ajax controllers. For example, to access sub menu 1 in read it will be /subMenu1 and to write for the same subMenu1 there are 3 ajax controller : /action1, /action2, /action3.

If I provide write access to subModule 1 I have to provide access to the 3 ajax controller.

This is the approach I'm going to take:
create table in DB for all the controllers. Here is an example of action1.

```
controller [id=1, name=action1, mapping=/action1, access_type=write]
```

Then for each controller, I create another table for userId and controller id. I will just have to check for each controller if the user has access in read/write before doing an action.

I will check this in a filter, so before I reach the controller.

Is it a good approach? should I use a better one?

Comment: Spring security has acls already http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/domain-acls.html  take a look at that, as it's much more generic and comes with tons of supporting plumbing

Comment: Ok, I'm having a look. Thanks !